# Specification pattern and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-5, specifications, generics

```
public interface IEntite
{
   int Id { get; set; }
   string NomEntite { get; }
}

public class SpecIdEntite<TEntite> : CompositeSpecification<TEntite> where TEntite : IEntite
{
   private int _id;
   public SpecIdEntite(int id)
   {
      _id = id;
   }

  public override Expression<Func<TEntite, bool>> IsSatisfiedBy()
  {
     return candidate => (candidate != null && candidate.Id == _id);
  }
}
```

When I try this specification I got this error : "Unable to cast the type 'Type Name' to type 'X'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types."

Anyone know how to implement this concept?

All my entities have an Id property and I want to use a generic specification

Comment: Can you show the code where this exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know exactly why, but the only thing that is missing is the `class` constraint on the type. This should works :

```
public interface IEntite
{
   int Id { get; set; }
   string NomEntite { get; }
}

public class SpecIdEntite<TEntite> : CompositeSpecification<TEntite> where TEntite : class, IEntite
{
   private int _id;
   public SpecIdEntite(int id)
   {
      _id = id;
   }

  public override Expression<Func<TEntite, bool>> IsSatisfiedBy()
  {
     return candidate => (candidate != null && candidate.Id == _id);
  }
}
```

The `class` constraint specifies that type type must be a reference type, as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).